# Awk add one more column is 3rd column equals string

Tags: awk, sed, vcf-vcard

I have a VCF file (tab delimited) where some "RPB" values went missing in the 2nd column and it sort of shifted the whole line to the left.

I have the following:

```
1   AF1=23  AC1=23
2   RPB=123 AF1=23  AC1=23
3   AF1=23  AC1=23
```

I need the following:

```
1   NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
2   RPB=123 AF1=23  AC1=23
3   NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
```

I tried that, it worked miserably..:

```
awk 'if($2="AF1%" {print $1,"\t"NULL"\t", print$2, print$3}' input.vcf > output.vcf
```

I have to import this VCF to MySQL so the tab delimitation has to be conserved .. any idea?

Comment: Can you confirm that its tab separated, or is it space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NF<4{sub(/\t/,"&NULL&")}1' file
1       NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
2       RPB=123 AF1=23  AC1=23
3       NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
```

By the way, you weren't TOO far off a functional solution with your attempt:

```
awk 'if($2="AF1%" {print $1,"\t"NULL"\t", print$2, print$3}' input.vcf
```

This minimally altered version would have produced the output you want:

```
awk '{if($2~/^AF1/) print $1 "\tNULL\t" $2 "\t" $3; else print}' input.vcf
```

but as you can see that's not a very idiomatic approach.

Comment: Your answers would be far more useful if you actually explained them, this isnt helping anybody except OP and only for this very specific instance.

Comment: I disagree, anyone who doesn't understand an answer and wants to can look up the manual and try to work it out and then if they can't figure it out for themselves they can ask questions. Much more beneficial to the learning process than spoonfeeding.

Comment: Your answer is the very definition of spoonfeeding, you have literally just given them an answer without them doing any work at all.

Comment: How would me providing an explanation in addition to the answer, as you suggested in your first comment, require more work on their part? You're talking in circles. Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: At least they would gain some knowledge that they could use outside of this specific incident. Im not trying to argue, its just that i had to look up the usage of `&` that you used. I just think instead of people having to search for information, which they might not be able to find easily(in this case it was easy to find), you could just provide a small explanation, even if it was just where to look to find how your answer works and possibly improve their knowledge of the subject. Also i didn't say spoonfeeding was bad so no circles have been talked in :)

Comment: Also is there any particular reason you used `/` over `"` in the sub ?

Comment: Yes, the 1st arg for sub() is an RE and `/` is the RE literal delimiter and I was specifying an RE literal. You can use `"` to specify a string literal that contains an RE but then you'd need to double-escape any RE metacharacters that you don't want treated as such due to strings being double-parsed. You should only use `"` delimiters in an RE context when you need to string concatenate segments to form a full RE, e.g. `var="def"; sub("abc" var,"")` to remove `abcdef`.

Comment: Thanks, never knew the actual reason for when to use `"` in RE context.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner would help you:

```
kent$  awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '!($2~/^RPB=/){$2="NULL\t"$2}7' file
1       NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
2       RPB=123 AF1=23  AC1=23
3       NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
```

Comment: This does not work correctly with the data given, since its space separated and not tab separated. From OPs test it seems to be tab separated so I changed to original post to tab. Some golfing: `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$2!~/^RPB=/{$2="NULL"FS$2}7'`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you shouldn't use regex, Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input.vcf |\
perl -ane '
    BEGIN{$c=0;$max_fields=0}
    $c2=0;
    foreach(@F){
        $a[$c][$c2]=$_;
        if( $c2  > $max_fields ) {
            $max_fields=$c2; 
        }
        $c2++
    }
    $c++;
    END{
        foreach $i (@a){
            while (@$i < $max_fields + 1 ){
                unshift (@$i,"NULL");   
            }  
        }
        foreach $i (@a){
            foreach $x (@$i){
                print $x,"\t";
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }'
```

Output:

```
bash test.sh 
NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23  
RPB=123 AF1=23  AC1=23  
NULL    AF1=23  AC1=23
```

Explanation:

1. The code above creates a 2D array (row/fields)
2. It also stores max_fields
3. for each row, if  number of fields is less than max_fields than insert "NULL"
   a the beginnig of the row

Answer (score 0):

Based on a tab delimited input file:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NF==3{$1=$1 OFS "NULL"} 1' input.vcf
```

where it could be altered to the following if the input file isn't tab delimited:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1 (NF==3 ? OFS "NULL" : "")} 1' input.vcf
```

In either, when `NF==3` the first field is re-assigned to contain the missing data.  In the first example, only the output delimiters of the altered lines need adjusting, but when the data isn't tab delimited, each line needs to be "re-computed" with re-assignment prior to the `1` which is printing the whole line.

The beauty of Ed's answer when the input file is tab delimited is that the whole line output delimiter isn't "re-computed" when the substitution takes place, because it's the first delimiter that's being replaced.